# OpenPyXL - ReadOnly: How to skip empty rows without knowing when they occur?

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

i'm pretty new to programming so please bear with me if my code is not nice and the answer is too obvious. :)

I want to parse an excel file into a directory so i can later access them via key. I won't know how the excel file will be structured before parsing it. So I can't just code it that way to skip a certain empty row since they will be random. 
For this, i am using Python 3 and OpenPyXl (Read Only). This is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pprint


# path to file
c = "test.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename=c, read_only=True, data_only=True)

# key for directory
data = {}
# list of worksheet names
wsname = []
# values in rows per worksheet
valuename = []


# took this odd numbers since pprint organizes the numbers weird when 1s and 10s are involved
# counter for row
k = 9
# counter for column
i = 10

# splits name of xlsx - file from .xlsx
workbook = c.split(".")[0]

data[workbook] = {}
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    # takes worksheet name and parses it into the wsname list
    wsname.append(ws.title)
    wsrealname = wsname.pop()
    worksheet = wsrealname
    data[workbook][worksheet] = {}
    for row in ws.rows:
        k += 1
        for cell in row:
            # reads value per row and column
            data[workbook][worksheet]["Row: " + str(k) + " Column: " + str(i)] = cell.value
            i += 1
        i = 10
    k = 9

pprint.pprint(data)
```

And with this i get output like this:

```
    {'test': {'Worksheet1': {'Row: 10 Column: 10': None,
                             'Row: 10 Column: 11': None,
                             'Row: 10 Column: 12': None,
                             'Row: 10 Column: 13': None,
                             'Row: 11 Column: 10': None,
                             'Row: 11 Column: 11': 'Test1',
                             'Row: 11 Column: 12': None,
                             'Row: 11 Column: 13': None}}}
```

Which is the Output i want, despite the fact they i want to skip in this example the whole Row 10, since all values are None and therefore empty.

As mentioned, I don't know when empty rows will occur so I can't just hardcode a certain row to be skipped. In Read Only Mode, if you print(row) there will be just 'EmptyCell' in the row like this:

```
(<EmptyCell>, <EmptyCell>, <EmptyCell>, <EmptyCell>)
```

I tried to let my program check with set() whether there are duplicates in the row "values".

```
if len(set(row)) == 1:
.....
```

but that doesn't solve this issue, since I get this Error Message:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'ReadOnlyCell'
```

If I compare the cell.value with 'None' and exlude all 'Nones', I get this Output:

```
{'test': {'Worksheet1': {'Row: 11 Column: 11': 'Test1'}}}
```

which is not beneficial, since I just want just to skip cells if the whole row is empty. Output should be like that:

```
{'test': {'Worksheet1': {'Row: 11 Column: 10': None,
                     'Row: 11 Column: 11': 'Test1',
                     'Row: 11 Column: 12': None,
                     'Row: 11 Column: 13': None}}}
```

So, could you please help in figuring out how to skip cells only if the complete row (and therefore all cells) is empty?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
from openpyxl.cell.read_only import EmptyCell

for row in ws:
     empty = all(isinstance(cell, EmptyCell) for cell in row) # or check if the value is None
```

NB. in read-only mode avoid multiple calls like `data[workbook][worksheet]['A1']` as they will force the library to parse the worsheet again and again

Comment: Thanks a lot Charlie! This works really well.

       `for row in ws:
        empty = all(isinstance(cell, EmptyCell) for cell in row)
        k += 1
        if empty == False:
            for cell in row:
                data[workbook][worksheet]["Row: " + str(k) + " Column: " + str(i)] = 
                cell.value`

I coded it like that, if Empty == False, it starts to parse the row. Is it the way you intended it to be used?

Is there a similar approach for skipping 'empty columns'?

Comment: Can't read your code but I don't see the need for `k` or the subsequent lookups, you already have everything. So what you do subsequently **looks** wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your custom generator which would yield only not empty rows:

```
def iter_rows_with_data(worksheet):
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
        if any(row):
            yield row
```